# Tweepy Search API stops with no errors, while searching back only 1 previous day

Tags: python, memory, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I'm new to Tweepy and running it via it's python module. I seem to be getting timed-out after a few hours searching hasgtags, but with no error messages - it just moves on to placing the tweets into my dataframe. I'm aware of the 7 day limit twitter poses to free developer accounts, as well as respecting twitters data mining limit by enabling `wait_on_rate_limit=True`. My goal is to run this daily on bigger hashtags like 'elonmusk' and get tweets for the past 24 hours, but Tweepy seems to timeout after a certain amount of tweets (last pull was 65k tweets and cut off after "now"-4 hours worth of tweets).

```
import tweepy
import pandas as pd

consumer_key = 'XXX'
consumer_secret = 'XXX'
access_token = 'XXX'
access_token_secret = 'XXX'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True,wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

d = []
start_date = pd.to_datetime('2021/2/14')
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=HashValue,count=20, lang="en", since=StartDate, tweet_mode='extended', show_user=True).items():
    full_noURL_tweet = [remove_url(tweet.full_text)]
    print('Writing tweets to the moooon...')
    d.append((tweet.created_at, full_noURL_tweet))
print('tweets loaded...')

df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=('date', 'full_tweet'))
```

I'd prefer not to use Tweepy's streaming tool, as I don't have the server/DB capability to run this 24/7.  Are there exception tests I can add to this loop to figure out why I'm getting kicked out?

## Edit

While running Task Manager concurrently, I'm noticing that I'm using 7.6GB (68.8MB Compressed) with 32GB total ram at 3000Mhz. Would this be a reason why I'm getting a timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I "solved" this timeout issue by increasing `count=20` to the maximum allowed by the api: `count=100`:
[See tweepy.search](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#search-methods)

This allowed me to increase the amount of tweets mined/request 5x, and I downloaded the entire dataset for my date range in much less time, so make sure to max out your count if you're going for big numbers!

I don't have a solid answer as to what this exact kicking issue is, but it seems that my code could do with some exception, and [this](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/sampled-stream/integrate/handling-disconnections) part of Tweepy's API might be the place to start